# Shape error with multiple inputs in my keras model

Tags: python, keras

I designed my neural network with keras.

But I have a shape problem when I try to train it with the fit method.

Here is my neural network in picture:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzMJ5.png

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Dense, Flatten, concatenate
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
import numpy as np

def create_model():
  lInputData  = Input(shape=(26 * 2, 1), name="DatasInput")
  lInputState = Input(shape=(2, 1), name="StateInput")

  mData = Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 8, strides = 4, activation = "relu", name = "DatasConvolution1")(lInputData)
  mData = Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 4, strides = 2, activation = "relu", name = "DatasConvolution2")(mData)
  mData = Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = "relu", name = "DatasConvolution3")(mData)
  mData = Flatten(name = "DatasAplatissement")(mData)
  mData = Model(inputs = lInputData, outputs = mData)

  mState = Flatten(name = "StateAplatissement")(lInputState)
  mState = Model(inputs = lInputState, outputs = mState)

  combined = concatenate([mData.output, mState.output], name="Fusion")

  lMixt = Dense(512, activation="relu", name="Classification1")(combined)
  lMixt = Dense(256, activation="relu", name="Classification2")(lMixt)
  lMixt = Dense(3, activation="linear",  name="Classification3")(lMixt)

  mFinal = Model(inputs=[mData.input, mState.input], outputs=lMixt)
  mFinal.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3), loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())

  return mFinal

m = create_model()

in1 = np.ones((1, 26 * 2, 1))
in2 = np.ones((1, 2, 1))
# fit don't work with this two shape.
out = np.ones((1, 3))
out = np.ones((3,))

print(m.predict([in1, in2]).shape)

m.fit([in1, in2], out, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

Here is the error i have:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1, 1
  y sizes: 3
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

I don't understand why I have this error because my shapes seem compatible with my neural network definition.

The error seems to be in my table containing the labels because the predict method works.

Thanks in advance for those who will help me. :)

Comment: you forgot to remove this line `out = np.ones((3,))`. also remove the `Sparse` in your loss function